# Is there a JavaScript/css method of making synced scrolling areas similar to "meld"?

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to have a couple of divs that scroll in sync with each other in a manner similar to the diff tool, [meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/meld_file1.png).  Note: as this is a static image, when you move the slider, the corresponding slider moves in sync with the other slider.  I need to do this both horizontally and vertically.

This is for a highly customized diff tool, some of the diffed lines are very long, and horizontal scrolling needs to happen.  This is within a web page, I use jQuery, but any css/JavaScript approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as easy as binding to the scroll event of each div and set the `.scrollTop` & `.scrollLeft` of the other div equal to scrolled div's `scrollTop` & `scrollLeft`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop && https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollLeft

**Edit:** Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/dHvJJ/

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a fixed font size. I also assume that the two containers are 2 divs.
here's my approach (in order to support webpage resizing properly):

1. convert the font-size from px to em
2. spit out an array of correspondences from the code (for example, you should already know that lines 32-33 from the first div correspond to line 22 in the second)
3. add event handlers for onscroll on both divs. Now the 'magic' is to calculate where the corresponding scrollbar should be, based on your info - it's pretty safe to assume that in order to scroll to line 32, you have to scroll 22 lines on the left side and so on.
   For the horizontal scroll I don't think it should be anything hard, simply scroll the corresponding div at the same scrollLeft position